# Are code changes supposed to persist across different branches?

Tags: git

I am confused about git branch behavior.

I have this git repo:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I create a local branch like so:

```
$ git checkout -b foo
Switched to a new branch 'foo'
$ git branch
* foo
  master
$ git status
On branch foo
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Now I change the README.md file.

```
$ date >> README.md 
$ git status
On branch foo
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   README.md

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Now I jump back to my master branch like so:

```
$ git checkout master
M   README.md
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
```

But when I do a git status I see that the README.md file has the modification from my foo branch! Shouldn't I be seeing the unmodified version of the README.md file?  What am I doing wrong here?

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   README.md


no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
$ tail README.md 
# README.md
-----------

Meanvoy is just an idea I had to replace envoy with facter and
a mean stack backend.
Fri Mar 17 13:43:04 PDT 2017
```

Comment: You didn't commit the readme file to your branch nor staged it. You need `git add <file>` and `git commit` on the branch to permanently have it there.

Comment: Ah! That does have the effect I am looking for.  I just didn't want to make anything permanent in my foo branch. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's first for a second consider what happens when you checkout a different branch *and doesn't have modified any files*.

When you do that, git will first move `HEAD` to the new place in history, this other branch, then git will update your working folder to contain the state of all files according to this other branch.

So for instance if you checkout a feature-branch, your working folder will be updated to reflect the current state of this feature-branch. Sounds good so far? Good.

Now, what happens if, before you check out this other branch, you modify a file?

Well, git will, unless explicitly told, try to avoid losing your changes. So what should it do? Refuse to checkout this other branch because you have modified some files *but not committed them*?

No, git will instead *try* to bring along the changes.

It will only do so if it is safe to do so. If the files are diverging between the two branches, git will refuse with an error along the lines of

```
$ git checkout feature/x
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        test1.txt
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

The fact that it didn't mean that the file was "safe" to bring along into this new branch. Still modified. Still uncommitted.

You will have to decide what to do with the file. If you wanted it to "remain" on the previous branch, you **should probably have committed it** before checking out the new branch.